# I am trying to add a feature to my voice assistant that if at any point I call out a wake word, the program starts to run. Any idea on how to do this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition

- I have made an assistant using python on Windows 10, now I am trying to add a wake word detection feature in it.
- I saw a couple a tutorials regarding the same but I cannot understand any of those and 1 that was working by Logical Spot, I am having trouble as it is showing that: _No module "*pywrap_tensorflow"* and I cannot figure out a way to install that module.
- I saw some tutorials about "Snowboy" and such but I cannot understand on how to work them.
- Can anyone help me or have any suggestions?

The error that I am getting is:

```
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: "but I cannot understand any of those" - Consider that you might be out-of-your-depth and need to understand those fundamentals first before continuing.

Comment: For one thing, it's spelled "Tens**or**flow", not "Tenserflow".

Comment: "`_pyway_tenserflow`" should be "`pywrap_tensorflow.py`", and it's part of the standard Tensorflow Python environment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py - you shouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant those things only as I was writing this from memory only so could not remember the exact spellings. But what should I do in this situation, like in the case of the error??

Comment: If you can't post the **exact error messages** then we cannot help you. Please reproduce the problem first, then post the exact details here.

Comment: Hey I made the changes and gave the error. Please help.

Comment: It looks like you're using a **very old** version of Tensorflow (the broken link to `os_setup.md` was fixed in 2017). You should upgrade first.